# How do I stagger the final boss' final (4th) form?

Tags: lightning-returns-final-fantasy-13

I can't get my stagger level to stick, no matter what I try, on the fourth form of the final boss.

I can get to the final form relatively easily so I don't think I am under-levelled in any way.

The guides I have searched online seem to give conflicting information about what spells stagger him effectively - what's the most effective method to achieve a stagger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best tip I can possible give is Elementa, combined with the Chaos's Revenge weapon you get after defeating Caius.

Elementa has a decent staggering power and can be cast repeatedly from the ground, removing the need to stay airborne to build stagger meter up. Chaos's Revenge allows you to stagger at 75% rather than 100%, making it a whole lot easier.

If you have any EP left, hit Overclock as much as possible when it looks like you have a clear window for attack - this allows you to repeatedly spam Elementa without running out of ATB. When he's finally staggered, he's easy enough to finish off even without using EP skills, so feel free to burn your entire supply just getting him to stagger.

Elementa can be obtained in the Temple of Valhala, or on the FFX Yuna DLC if you have it.

Comment: I actually managed to beat the boss without staggering him but it took me 3 and a half hours. I will have to give this a try on my second playthrough.